# How to group layers into one

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to group layers but the option is greyed out. The layers are based on drawing using pen tools. How can I group layers into one?
[image: Gorup option grey out]

Comment: It's not possible to group layers. Layers aren't objects. Objects exist within layers. If you have objects you want to group, make sure they are in the same layer.

Comment: Select objects not layers. The Object menu dropdown is only active when object is selected

Answer (score 4):

> Object Groups

You can create groups by selecting objects and pressing `ctrl/cmd + G`
[image]
[image]

> Layer Grouping

Grouping layers is not quite the same as in photoshop. You can stack layers by drag and dropping layers onto an other layer. It can help to organise your file. But unlike in photoshop (with layer styles, effects and masks) illustrator groups and layers don't have much functionality.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You **can't** "group" layers using the `Object > Group` menu item. Layers are *layers*, not objects. It is only possible to "group" objects.

You however, **can** create a new layer and combine other layers as **sublayers**. This is kind of a pseudo-group.

Merely highlight the layers in the **Layers Panel** and from the Panel Menu choose `Collect in New Layer`.

[image]

Again, this isn't really a "group", but rather a new layer with sub-layers. But as a new layer you can lock/hide/select it to control the internal sublayers as if it were a "group".